# Why a simple query take too much time PostgreSQL?

Tags: performance, postgresql

Why a simple query take long time to execute more than 1 second (you can see the log file: http://tny.cz/1fa5d842 ) the query passed in prepared statement.
In console it's executed in less than 30ms.
The query is too simple. Can you please help to resolve this issue? 
Thanks a lot for your help. 
OS : windows 7
Postgresql 9.3.2.

RhodiumToad help me to solve this issue.
there was a function (equal) writin in (pl/pgsql) whitch make the equal between number and character. i changed this function from pl/pgsql to a simple function inline. and the index works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive the problem is that the data type of the column doesn't match the datatype of the value:

```
WHERE fda_agriculteur.FDA_Agriculteur_ID = $1
```

and

```
$1 = '1054998'
```

It may be casting the column to match the text type of the value, so the index can't be used.

Try an explicit cast to the same type as the column:

```
WHERE fda_agriculteur.FDA_Agriculteur_ID = $1::int
```

I have seen postgres be particularly moronic with casting. I had this exact problem many years ago - looks like things haven't changed.

Comment: thanks man for your answer.
RhodiumToad help me to solve this issue (it's like you said)
there was a function (equal) writin in (pl/pgsql) whitch make the equal between number and character. i changed the function from pl/pgsql to a simple function inline. and the query works normally.

Comment: it's done :) sorry can't vote don't have the reputation for that lol

Answer (score 0):

There cannot be difference between querying through application vs. querying through console. Only reason for your console query can return faster is if you have already run the query once before to warm up the cache. Else even from console it should take 1+ seconds.

Log lines you posted show that your query is doing sequential scan.

```
`Seq Scan on public.fda_agriculteur  (cost=0.00..115524.50 rows=53792 width=24) (actual time=463.383..1122.579 rows=1 loops=1)`
```

That will definitely take lot more time than index scan. It will get progressively worse as the number of records in the table grow. You should create index on `fda_agriculteur.FDA_Agriculteur_ID`. That will dramatically improve the query speed.

Comment: the column FDA_Agriculteur_ID  is a primary key in the table

Answer (score 0):

I've never used postgresql, but your logfile mentions something that sounds like a clue.

```
Seq Scan on public.fda_agriculteur  (cost=0.00..115524.50 rows=53792 width=24)
    (actual time=463.383..1122.579 rows=1 loops=1)
```

This sounds a lot like a table scan in SQL Server. Do you have any index on your [presumed] primary key column?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_FDA_Agriculteur ON fda_agriculteur ( FDA_Agriculteur_ID )
```

Comment: thanks man, solve the problem.
i will post the solution as soon as possible. 
thanks to RhodiumToad in postgresql support.